# What is the function to find the frames in a webpage from the Chrome console?

Tags: javascript

I want to search the frames inside a webpage. What is the appropriate function.
I am trying to find out the input type checkbox with follwing.

```
"Top level frame"
"Top level frame"
$("#input")
```

Comment: the problem is to access to frames?

Answer (score -1):

After some research i am able to find the frame inside the webpage from the Chrome console. I have done the following things.
1. First i searched the total iframe 
var Frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
2. To Print the frame by simply write the frame and press enter key.
3. After executing the step 2. i found the total count of the frame. But for filtering the count i found the frame no. 9 is required ,so i execute the step as follows.
var Frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[9]
3. Actually i tried to find the input inside the frame so i need to find the content of the frame. so i have done like as. 
doc=Frame.contentDocument

## document

3. Now doc.getElementByTagName('input')
   Now i found all the inputs inside the frame